# How i cant get all my itens of combobox1 and send to a multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiline

Hello guys a have a problem with my combobox sometimes because it is variable
sometimes have 1 item other times it has more than 10+ I need send all items listed in my `combobox1` to my `textbox1` multiline.

Example below:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by me :

```
For Each VARIAVEL_DE_STRING As String In ComboBox1.Items
                txt_atividades_secundarias_encontradas.Text &= VARIAVEL_DE_STRING & vbCrLf
            Next
```